# Intellij Copyright velocity template - how to add file creation date

Tags: java, intellij-idea, velocity, copyright-display

I would like to add the date the file was created and the date the file was last updated on my java project on IntelliJ. I was able to add the last modification date via `$file.lastModified`.

Does anyone know how to add the date on which the file was created?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible at the moment, please [vote for this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207291).